# Mac App Rejected for Use of Non-Public APIs

Tags: macos, appstore-approval

Mac app recently rejected from Mac App Store for Use of Non-Public APIs (see below), and I'm unsure how to go about fixing the problem -- mainly because I don't fully understand the problem itself.

I've tried using otool -L, and nm -u, to get a better idea of the issue, but I get a "can't map file" warning in terminal.

Also important to note I'm using PyObjC in the application, which I have a feeling is the source of this issue.

Anybody know how to resolve this?

> 2.5
>
> The use of non-public APIs can lead to
>   a poor user experience should these
>   APIs change in the future, and is
>   therefore not permitted. The following
>   non-public APIs are included in your
>   application:
>
> 'pthread_key_init_np', framework:
>   '/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib'
>   'auto_assign_weak_reference',
>   framework: '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_collect', framework:
>   '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_collect_multithreaded',
>   framework: '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_collection_parameters',
>   framework: '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_read_weak_reference', framework:
>   '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_zone_add_root', framework:
>   '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_zone_allocate_object',
>   framework: '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_zone_assert_thread_registered',
>   framework: '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_zone_atomicCompareAndSwap',
>   framework: '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_zone_atomicCompareAndSwapPtr',
>   framework: '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_zone_clear_stack', framework:
>   '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_zone_create', framework:
>   '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_zone_dump', framework:
>   '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_zone_erase_associative_refs',
>   framework: '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_zone_get_associative_ref',
>   framework: '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_zone_get_layout_type',
>   framework: '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_zone_is_collecting', framework:
>   '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_zone_is_finalized', framework:
>   '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_zone_is_valid_pointer',
>   framework: '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_zone_register_datasegment',
>   framework: '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_zone_register_thread',
>   framework: '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_zone_release', framework:
>   '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_zone_retain', framework:
>   '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_zone_retain_count', framework:
>   '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_zone_root_write_barrier',
>   framework: '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_zone_set_associative_ref',
>   framework: '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_zone_set_class_list', framework:
>   '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_zone_set_write_barrier',
>   framework: '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_zone_size', framework:
>   '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_zone_start_monitor', framework:
>   '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_zone_unregister_datasegment',
>   framework: '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_zone_unregister_thread',
>   framework: '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>   'auto_zone_write_barrier_memmove',
>   framework: '/usr/lib/libauto.dylib'
>
> If you have defined methods in your
>   source code with the same names as the
>   above-mentioned APIs, we suggest
>   altering your method names so that
>   they no longer collide with Apple's
>   private APIs to avoid your application
>   being flagged in future submissions.
>
> Additionally, one or more of the
>   above-mentioned APIs may reside in a
>   library included with your
>   application. If you do not have access
>   to the library's source, you may be
>   able to search the compiled binary
>   using “strings" or “otool" command
>   line tools. The “strings" tool can
>   output a list of the methods that the
>   library calls and “otool -ov" will
>   output the Objective-C class
>   structures and their defined methods.
>   These techniques can help you narrow
>   down where the problematic code
>   resides.

Comment: You're better off asking in the Apple Developer Forums, assuming you have a paid developer account

Answer (score 1):

PyObjC framework is importing (directly or through another library that is using) these libraries "/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib" and "/usr/lib/libauto.dylib" as mentioned in the message. Those two libraries contain certain methods (also mentioned within the message) that

> collide with Apple's private APIs

I guess those methods collide with the QTKit framework (see [API notes for QTKit](http://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/apinotes/QTKit.html)). Now there are 2 possibilities:

1. Remove that problematic library if you can at build time
2. Talk with the guys from PyObjC to see if they need to change their API